# SharePoint Online, exporting SharePoint lists

Tags: sql, ssis, sharepoint-online

tl;dr - Don't use SharePoint list to store any data that might need to be exported in an automatic fashion, and power automate is well short of even being half baked. What follows might be helpful for someone doing the same thing I tried, but only if there is a very small amount of data stored on the SharePoint list.

My use case is straight forward, pull the contents of a SharePoint list on a regular basis to upload them to an azure DB. Simple right, turns out it's far from it.

This seems like a good use case for SSIS, and that's the first pain point. You see ssis doesn't have a connector for sharepoint list, so it will have to be a scripted source, which makes it really fragile.  So instead this looks like a job for power automate. It's advertised on sharepoint online, has a built in get items feature for SharePoint list, seems nice and easy.

The next question that faces you is what destination do you want, initially I wanted to create a flat file in a local folder, that way I could use SSIS to import the data as part of a larger job that will use that data. However you need to install a local gateway inside your network to do that, and direct quote from my IT support staff after examining the software requirements was "No, Hell No". I can't drop the file on SharePoint, because I don't have anyway to get it from SharePoint automatically. After briefly considering FTP, I decided to just use the sql insert option, which is a premium feature costing 15 bucks a month. Spoiler, it's not worth 15 bucks a month, it's very obviously in early development.

I struggled a bit to get this set up since there is next to no documentation for power automate outside of the boiler plate MS documentation. Turns out the insert step is incapable of even minor conversions, so I had to alter the table to match the data types in SharePoint, and having no earthly idea what the data types were there was some trial and error to get the sql tables data types to match SharePoint's. However, whenever there is a change to the underlying sql table, you have to delete and recreate the insert rows widget, because there is no way to update the stored schema information. This is not documented anywhere, and figured this out via trial and error.

Eventually I get my first successful run of the flow. Wonderful, I check the table in the azure DB and there are only 100 rows. Odd, there is like 50k rows in the list. Turns out that there is a hidden default of 100 for the get items widget, this is not explained anywhere, you are not given any warnings, so I had to google it. To get around this you have to enable pagination and set a row limit greater than a value you think the list could ever reach.

Now realizing there is a lot of data, I try to set up a filter so I can pull in only the data for the prior month. Turns out you can't use expressions in the filter clause (guess that's a tbd feature), you have to use fixed values, which makes prior month a non starter since this job needs to be run on a schedule.

Next I try to use the sort option on the "Created" column (note to reader, this is all case sensitive which is annoying but manageable) and a top filter to get a few thousand rows of the most recent data. Turns out if your list has more than 5000 rows, the get items step will fail. You can get around this by creating an index on the column you plan on sorting by, catch 22, you can't create an index on a table with more than 20k rows. Since I have 50k rows this method is completely non-functional for me.

Very near the end of my rope I think, "Fine, I'll just grab all of the rows". Turns out, the get items widget is slow, super slow. The goal was to run this during non-business hours, so that's not a deal breaker by itself, the 10 minute timeout for each step in the flow was though. This is a small data set of merely 50k rows, and it takes power automate more than 10 minutes to pull the data.

So please learn from my pain, avoid SharePoint list and power automate like the half baked cash grabs they are. If you see something I did wrong, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Is this question really related to the <sql> _language_? "_Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL._"

Comment: I could include the data structure changes necessitated by this, but the destination is a sql DB and the whole thing doesn't make much sense without that.

Comment: The ISO/ANSI SQL specification doesn't even deal with indexes. It seems more like you're having problems with one SQL dbms, not the language itself.